# Is it possible to ask for temporary increase on the quota of Mirror API Request

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

We are going to have a important demo for our glassware, but we keep hitting the limit of Mirror API, now we use apply different project client id to handle it, but not convenience.

Is it possible to ask for a temporary increase on the quota and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask for a permanent increase using the form at https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/form

The form is intended to collect information to make your Glassware public, but you can fill in "n/a" for the non-relevant portions and say that you're not trying to make it public yet.

Comment: Thanks Prisoner, our demo app is still in PoC phase, so I am not sure whether Google accept it, did you submit a similar one before, and was is get approved?

Comment: The team has probably been out on vacation. If you don't hear anything by next week, you may want to ping one of the developer relations people here or in the community.

Comment: I can confirm this advice. The official guidance is to fill out the form and mention that you'd like more quota to pursue your development.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, we didn't fill out the form for latest demo as we don't have time to wait for the approval. We just setup multiple glass project to overcome the quota limit. Once I got time, I will try to fill out the form as what you advised.